# How to get long pressed button's current title

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I am using UILongPressGestureRecognizer on many buttons and when I long press on it I want to get its current title.I am using same tag for all buttons for a different job so I cant use tags to get the title.Since my sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer I can't use sender.currentTitle! in my action too.Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
for i in self.masalarView.subviews{
        if i.tag == 102{
            i.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
for i in self.masalarArray{
            let masa = UIButton(frame : CGRect(x : Double(i.masaButonLeft)! , y : Double(i.masaButonTop)! , width : Double(i.masaButonGenislik)! , height : Double(i.masaButonYukselik)!))

            masa.setTitle(i.masaTableName, for: .normal)
            masa.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.masaAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            masa.tag = 102
            let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed(sender:)))
            masa.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
            self.masalarView.addSubview(masa)
        }
 }


func longPressed(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    //This is where i want to get my long pressed button title
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UILongPressGestureRecognizer got a property named view which return the view the gesture recognizer is attached to. you can cast view to UIButton and then read the title.

```
if let button = sender.view as? UIButton {
    print(button.title)
}
```

Comment: It works but button.title should be button.currentTitle in my case.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the super class of UILongPressGestureRecognizer UIGestureRecognizer it has a property called [view](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624212-view) that is the view that sent the gesture.  Prefer named variables to tags.  There are very few reasons to use tags.

Edit in case its not clear, UIButton is a subclass of UIView so you test for referential equality with triple equals:

```
if longPressGestureRecognizer.view === mybutton { // do stuff here }
```